Blowing up to eliminate intersections
A problem from Hartshorne asks to resolve the indeterminacies of a rational function.  See V.Ex.5.1.  Given a smooth surface $X$ and a rational function $f \in K(X)$, $f$ determines a rational map to $\mathbb{P}^1$.  Writing the divisor for $f$ as $(f) = \sum n_iP_i$, the hint suggests performing embedded resolution on the reduced divisor obtained from $(f)$ and then to blow up further in order to make the zero curves disjoint from the polar curves.  My question is, why not blow up the intersection points at the start?  If the goal is to get the zeros and poles disjoint, doesn't blowing up their intersection points do this at once?

No. Try blowing up two tangent curves and see what happens. Also, for your future use of the site, it's better to edit and improve your post instead of posting again (thank you for the additions you've made; do consider checking out How to ask a good question for more about what we expect here).

I understand that more than one blow up may be required to eliminate intersection points in this manner.  As you said, the example of a conic tangent to a line shows this.  I am wondering whether the process always terminates when there is no transversality.

Yes, it always finishes, but the best tool you have at this point in the text to show that is citing the proof of the existence of an embedded resolution.

Writing $P_i$ for curves is confusing.
